# ifelse statement with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am familiar with writing `ifelse()` statements and they are very useful, but when they have multiple conditions they appear to be very inefficient. I am curious if there is a more efficient way to write them. For example, if I had the following dataframe

```
test <- data.frame(col = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
test$col <- factor(test$col)

  col
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

I could write

```
test$col2 <- ifelse(test$col == "a" | test$col == "b" | test$col == "c", "x", "z")
test

  col col2
1   a    x
2   b    x
3   c    x
4   d    z
5   e    z
```

Here I have essentially written the same thing (`test$col ==`) three times within the one `ifelse()` statement. How can I write the code such that I am only typing `test$col ==` once?

I appreciate that the below is incorrect and does not work, but my guess at something like this would be

```
test$col2 <- ifelse(test$col == c("a", "b", "c"), "x", "z")

OR

test$col2 <- ifelse(test$col == "a" | "b" | "c", "x", "z")
```

It is inefficient to be writing the code `test$col ==` multiple times. Can this be avoided in such an `ifelse()` statement?

Comment: `test$col %in% c("a", "b", "c")`

Comment: @zephryl This is not correct, or at least ambiguous. Wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77671069/6574038) on that below, why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
test <- data.frame(col = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
test$col <- factor(test$col)

test$col2 <- ifelse(test$col %in% c("a","b","c"), "x", "z")
```

Comment: Unless data.frame$col does not contain any NAs. See answer by @jay.sf

Answer (score 1):

**Be careful when using `%in%` for this!**

The reason is, `NA` are removed and the data gets biased.

Consider this data frame with `NA`s in `col`

```
> test
    col
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6  <NA>
7  <NA>
8  <NA>
9  <NA>
10 <NA>
11 <NA>
```

and compare both approaches, first using multiple `==` separated by `|`, second naïvely using `%in%`.

```
> test <- transform(test,
+           col1=ifelse(col == 'a' | col == 'b' | col == 'c', "x", "z"),
+           col2=ifelse(col %in% c("a","b","c"), "x", "z")
+ )
```

While the first approach reflects the correct statistical properties

```
> with(test, t.test(col1 == 'x', col1 == 'z'))[c('estimate', 'p.value')] |> unlist()
estimate.mean of x estimate.mean of y            p.value 
          0.600000           0.400000           0.579584
```

The second approach inflates the `z` and biases the data.

```
> with(test, t.test(col2 == 'x', col2 == 'z'))[c('estimate', 'p.value')] |> unlist()
estimate.mean of x estimate.mean of y            p.value 
        0.27272727         0.72727273         0.03356288*
```

A possible solution is torecover original `NA`s using `replace`.

```
> test <- transform(test,
+                   col3=ifelse(col %in% c("a","b","c"), "x", "z") |> 
+                     replace(is.na(col), NA)
+ )
> with(test, t.test(col3 == 'x', col3 == 'z'))[c('estimate', 'p.value')] |> unlist()
estimate.mean of x estimate.mean of y            p.value 
          0.600000           0.400000           0.579584
```

We could write a custom operator `` `%IN%` `` for this.

```
> `%IN%` <- function(x, y, na.omit=FALSE) {
+   r <- x %in% y
+   if (na.omit) r else replace(r, is.na(x), NA)
+ }
> test <- transform(test,
+                   col4=ifelse(col %IN% c("a","b","c"), "x", "z")
+ )
> with(test, t.test(col4 == 'x', col4 == 'z'))[c('estimate', 'p.value')] |> unlist()
estimate.mean of x estimate.mean of y            p.value 
          0.600000           0.400000           0.579584
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(col = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex option:

```
test$col2 <- ifelse(grepl("a|b|c", test$col), "x", "z")

  col col2
1   a    x
2   b    x
3   c    x
4   d    z
5   e    z
```

If it is possible for your data to contain NAs you need to change the code like this:

```
test <- data.frame(col = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", NA))
test$col2[!is.na(test$col)] <- ifelse(grepl("a|b|c", test$col[!is.na(test$col)]), "x", "z")
   col col2
1    a    x
2    b    x
3    c    x
4    d    z
5    e    z
6 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: No, I think you didn't get the point, `<NA>` should **not** become `z`.

Comment: @jay.sf Now I got your point. See the edited answer.

Comment: That's okish, however if OP wants only `col` altered but  doesn't  want `col2` we'll get problems, because the information on the `NA`s is lost.

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you! You are a cool tester/QA! I made the third edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Dplyr's `case_when()`. Not the most concise code, but it also works:

```
test$col2 <- case_when(
  test$col == "a" ~ "x",
  test$col == "b" ~ "x",
  test$col == "c" ~ "x",
  test$col != "a" ~ "z",
  test$col != "b" ~ "z",
  test$col != "c" ~ "z",
)

  col col2
1   a    x
2   b    x
3   c    x
4   d    z
5   e    z
```