# How is non-existing column created when using `<-` with boolean subset?

Tags: r

Consider this data frame.

```
> (df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, NA, NA)))
   x
1  1
2  2
3 NA
4 NA
```

How is non-existing *foo* column created here?

```
> `<-`(df$foo[!is.na(df$x)], 999)
> df
   x foo
1  1 999
2  2 999
3 NA  NA
4 NA  NA
```

I need to initialize it first when using `within`.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, NA, NA))
> df |> within(foo[!is.na(x)] <- 999)
Error: object 'foo' not found
> df |> within({foo <- NA_real_; foo[!is.na(x)] <- 999})
   x foo
1  1 999
2  2 999
3 NA  NA
4 NA  NA
```

Couldn't find documentation on that behavior.

Comment: Which part do you find surprising? Doesn't the `$` sign usually let us both modify existing columns as well as create new ones, e.g., `df$bar <- 999`?

Comment: @dufei Note the subset in brackets, and I asked _how_ it is created, and why it won't work in `within`.

Comment: I think it'll have to do with the semantics of `$`. `n <- is.na(df$x); df$foo[n] <- 999` is a slightly less convoluted example

Comment: `\`$\`(df, foo)` actually first gives `NULL`, `\`<-\`(\`$\`(df, foo), 999)` creates a new column foo. But how can it be subsetted before it exists `\`<-\`(\`$\`(df, foo)[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], 999)`?

Comment: Interesting side effect which also occurs with `[[` and combining with `<-`. See [fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/AG5dPFcdomv). Good question for R core team?

Comment: I thought this was just a case of subassignment (see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subassignment) but I am not familar with the semantics of `within()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `` typeof(`<-`) == "special" ``, so evaluation of the arguments (the left and right hand side expressions) is nonstandard.  You have to look at the C sources to know when, where, and in what order the (sub)expressions are evaluated.

Calls like `x$s[i] <- y`, including where `x` is a list not yet defining `s`, are called "complex (sub)assignments" and handled in the `do_set->applydefine->evalseq` call stack in [`eval.c`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/eval.c).

`within(x, s[i] <- y)` triggers the same stack but crucially with left hand side of the form `s[i]`, no longer `x$s[i]`.  The code path for expressions `s[i]` expects `s` to be defined in the evaluation environment, which here is `x` enclosed by the calling environment of `within`.  The code path for expressions `x$s[i]` does not, because the semantics there are something like:

```r
`*tmp*` <- x$s
`*tmp*`[i] <- y
x$s <- `*tmp*`
```

The behaviour that you observe for not-yet-defined `s` is thus inherited from subassignment to `NULL`; see `do_subassign_dflt` in [`subassign.c`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/subassign.c):

```r
`*tmp*` <- NULL
`*tmp*`[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)] <- 999
`*tmp*`
## [1] 999 999  NA  NA
```

And that behaviour *is* somewhat documented in `help("Extract")`: `NULL` is "coerced as needed to accept the values", i.e., coerced to `double(0L)`, before subassignment takes place.  It is understandable that R-core does not document the exact behaviour in edge cases; they have much less freedom to change whatever they document.

The details in the C sources are pretty gruesome and comments there indicate as much:

```c
/*
 *  Assignments for complex LVAL specifications. This is the stuff that
 *  nightmares are made of ...  Note that "evalseq" preprocesses the LHS
 *  of an assignment.  Given an expression, it builds a list of partial
 *  values for the expression.  For example, the assignment x$a[3] <- 10
 *  with LHS x$a[3] yields the (improper) list:
 *
 *   (eval(x$a[3])  eval(x$a)  eval(x)  .  x)
 *
 *  (Note the terminating symbol).  The partial evaluations are carried
 *  out efficiently using previously computed components.
 */
```

If you *really* want to dig into it, then run R under a debugger, set a break point at `do_set`, and proceed through the stack after evaluating the assignment.  I am assuming that your installation of R was built with `-g -O0` in `CFLAGS`; you can check with `R CMD CONFIG CFLAGS`.  See, e.g., the relevant section of [`R-exts`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Wasn't able to `(gdb) break do_set`; my `gdb` won't break at that point. Anyway, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77671083/6574038) led me to ask this question. So can we conclude that this is an intended behavior, actually a feature, and we can virtually create `s` on the fly, or should we consider this some sort of side effect?

Comment: See my latest edit ... You may need to debug an R built with different compiler flags.  And, yes, I think that the behaviour is intended, even if it is sparsely documented.

Comment: Thanks for updates, very informative. I used `./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-debug CFLAGS='-g -O0' CXXFLAGS='-g -O0'`.